# Same y-axis scale with ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use ggarrange to combine two plots into a single one, and use the same scaling for the y-axis to make it easier to compare the values, in my case, temperature calculations.
This is my sample data:

```
    Sample  Group   Temperature_A   Temperature_B
1   Sample01    A   20  34
2   Sample02    B   21  31
3   Sample03    A   25  35
4   Sample04    A   18  27
5   Sample05    B   19  29
6   Sample06    A   22  32
7   Sample07    B   23  33
8   Sample08    B   17  28
9   Sample09    A   15  26
10  Sample10    B   28  39
```

Using the following code, I get the following plot:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Group, Temperature_A)) +
 geom_boxplot()

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(Group, Temperature_B)) +
 geom_boxplot()

plate <- ggarrange(p1, p2, align = "hv")

plate
```

[image: Sample Plot]

What I would like to have is for them to share their y-axis so that I can easily compare the two temperature calculation methods. I can do this manually with `+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(a,b))` where I set the appropriate values for a and b, however, I have a lot of different dataframes with different temperature ranges. Ideally, I would use the lowest value (+ some space) from both plots, and the highest value (+ some space) from both plots for the limits of both plots. Is there a way to achieve this?

My manual approach and the desired output:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Group, Temperature_A)) +
 geom_boxplot() + 
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10, 40))

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(Group, Temperature_B)) +
 geom_boxplot() + 
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10, 40))

plate <- ggarrange(p1, p2, align = "hv")

plate
```

[image: Desiered output]

Comment: This seems like a good case for facets. Is there any reason you wouldn't like facets?

Comment: No good reason other than I don't know how to use them and I am used to ggarrange, which is pretty straigth forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just to illustrate how you could use facets. Because you have two columns for temperature, this is called the 'wide format'. If you reshape the data to the long format, you can easily use facets.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(text = "    Sample  Group   Temperature_A   Temperature_B
1   Sample01    A   20  34
2   Sample02    B   21  31
3   Sample03    A   25  35
4   Sample04    A   18  27
5   Sample05    B   19  29
6   Sample06    A   22  32
7   Sample07    B   23  33
8   Sample08    B   17  28
9   Sample09    A   15  26
10  Sample10    B   28  39", header = TRUE)

# Reshape
long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(
  df, c("Temperature_A", "Temperature_B"), 
  values_to = "Temperature", names_to = "Temp_name"
)

# Example of facets
ggplot(long) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(Group, Temperature)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Temp_name)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is not a good answer from my point of view. For example, I already have a plot which uses facets, and I combind four of these plots into one plot with ggarrange. The title of the question was not "Same y-axis scale" but "Same y-axis scale with ggarrange" and you have chosen to bypass the part "with ggarrange" so that the desired output matches what the OP needs, but cannot be generalized to all other cases. It would be nice if answers on SO were generalizable to all other cases instead of just handing out the solution to the OP on a plate.

Comment: Well sure, this might not be a good answer to the verbatim question. However, sometimes OP asks a question to solve a problem, and a solution may or may not involve the actual question. To what degree an answer can be generalised depends on the question. In this case, I specifically asked OP in the comments under the post why facets would not solve the problem, and the reason was that OP wasn't familiar with them. Hence, I preface this answer by 'this is just to show...'. If you feel that I've inadequately addressed the problem, feel free to downvote the answer or post your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with teunbrand. Here is an slightly modified approach:

1. bring data in long format
2. ignore outlieres `outlier.shape = NA`
3. adapt `ylim` and
4. `facet_wrap`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = starts_with("Temperature"), 
        names_to = "Temperature",
        values_to = "values"
    ) 


ggplot(df1, aes(Group, values)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(10, 40)) +
    facet_wrap(~Temperature) + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for J.Doe who appeared unsatisfied with the current accepted answer, I'll post another answer which again ignores the 'ggarrange' part, but generalises better. Instead, the {patchwork} package is used.

Notably, you can use `& scale_y_continuous(...)` to apply a scale to all previous plots. You can use the `plot + plot` syntax to combine plots.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

df <- read.table(text = "    Sample  Group   Temperature_A   Temperature_B
1   Sample01    A   20  34
2   Sample02    B   21  31
3   Sample03    A   25  35
4   Sample04    A   18  27
5   Sample05    B   19  29
6   Sample06    A   22  32
7   Sample07    B   23  33
8   Sample08    B   17  28
9   Sample09    A   15  26
10  Sample10    B   28  39", header = TRUE)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Group, Temperature_A)) +
  geom_boxplot()

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(Group, Temperature_B)) +
  geom_boxplot()

p1 + p2 & scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10, 40))
```

[image]

The same works if you have a list of plots and use `wrap_plot()`.

```r
plot_list <- list(p1, p2)

wrap_plots(plot_list) & scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10, 40))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>