# Same y-axis range with ggarrange if I am already using facets and cannot use them again

Tags: r, ggplot2

my question is basically a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68540905/same-y-axis-scale-with-ggarrange). However, the problem is that in the said question the answer completely bypasses the fact that `ggarrange` is used and instead transfers the whole issue to be handled by the facets functionality of ggplot.

This doesn't work for me since I already am using facets in the sub-plots and I cannot use them again.

Here is some example code. I am wondering how to achieve that the two plots which are joined with ggarrange have the same range of y-axis (of course, not setting the limits manually).

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_split(vs) %>% 
  map(~ggplot(., aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
        geom_point() +
        facet_grid(rows = vars(am), cols = vars(gear))) %>% 
  ggarrange(plotlist = .)
```

[image]

As you can see, the left image's y-axis ranges from 2 to 5, while the right plot's y-axis ranges from 1.5 to 3.5. How can I make them be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm once again arguing for abandoning the 'ggarrange' approach, this time in favour of the {patchwork} package, which allows you to apply an operation to all previous plots. In this case, we can use `& scale_y_continuous(limits = ...)` to set the limits for all plots.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(patchwork)

mtcars %>% 
  group_split(vs) %>% 
  map(~ggplot(., aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
        geom_point() +
        facet_grid(rows = vars(am), cols = vars(gear))) %>% 
  wrap_plots() &
  scale_y_continuous(limits = range(mtcars$wt))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Simpler solution and nice reminder that patchwork allows to add layers to all plots after wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to compute and add the range of your x and y variables to your dataset before splitting, which could then be used to set the limits.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(c(mpg, wt), list(range = ~list(range(.x))))) %>%
  group_split(vs) %>% 
  map(~ggplot(., aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
        geom_point() +
        scale_x_continuous(limits = .$mpg_range[[1]]) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = .$wt_range[[1]]) +
        facet_grid(rows = vars(am), cols = vars(gear))) %>% 
  ggarrange(plotlist = .)
```

[image]